# Access Denied : Invalid according to Policy: Policy expired

Tags: amazon-s3, http-post

When trying to do Browser upload using http post , I am getting an error :

```
(Error)
(Code)AccessDenied(/Code)
(Message) Invalid according to Policy: Policy expired.
(/Message)
(RequestId) 6C79F2BC4E51766A (/RequestId)
(HostId) 
4uzKezeAmS/y0EAz47QevCu9Jh/3ivPxYRbOYn/Df+JoQnAgXNK+faFOmkDSlOukwynxUPzp4Uk= 
(/HostId)
(/Error)
```

I tried changing my system clock time ,
I checked with expiration time set to current date, future date upto 5min, 1 day, 1 month, 1 year

Post Policy is:

```
{  "expiration": "2019-06-06T13:45:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
{"bucket": "tokendatabase"},
["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
{"acl": "public-read-write"},
{"success_action_redirect": ""},
["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
{"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
{"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"},
["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],
{"x-amz-credential": "<Access KEY>/20180122/us-east-2/s3/aws4_request"},
{"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
{"x-amz-date": "20180122T000000Z" }
]
}
```

Comment: please check your bucket policy

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the service that you signed this policy almost three months ago:

```
{"x-amz-credential": "<Access KEY>/20180122/us-east-2/s3/aws4_request"},
{"x-amz-date": "20180122T000000Z" }
```

It is now expired, because the credential for 2018-01-22 was only valid until 2018-01-30.

> the signing key you use in signature calculation is valid for up to seven days.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html

The source of the above quote is from a different context in the documentation, but is applicable here.  The signing keys used with a Signature V4 are tied to the date you signed the request (or the date that you claim that you did, in this case), the AWS region, and the specific service, and are invalid in any other context, including more than 7 days in the past (if used in the "future," relative to the date you provide).

The values from the `x-amz-credential` and `x-amz-date` need to match each other with respect to the date component, and should be derived from your system clock at the time you sign the policy.